# Pyspark - how to explode json schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset having below schema

```
|-- soap:E1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- soap:E2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- RetrieveResponse: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- RetrieveResult: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- poObject: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- @Active: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- @id: string (nullable = true) 
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- @Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- CustomFieldDetail: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- @FieldId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- @FieldName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- @FieldType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- @FieldValue: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- xsi:@type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- soap:Header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- SessionHeader: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |--SessionVal: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to explode this and retrieve only fields under the json object - "element". How can this be achieved in pyspark?

Comment: Can you share sample data along with expected output here?

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.select(f.explode("soap:E1.soap:E2.RetrieveResponse.RetrieveResult.poObject").alias("c")).select(f.col("c.*"))
```

You have to do it in the two split selects due to the `explode`.
The resulting dataframe will have the following schema:

```
root
|-- @Active: boolean (nullable = true)
|-- @id: string (nullable = true) 
|-- @Code: string (nullable = true)
|-- CustomFieldDetail: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- @FieldId: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- @FieldName: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- @FieldType: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- @FieldValue: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- xsi:@type: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: cannot resolve '`poObject`' given input columns: [soap:E1]; 
I am getting this error when I tried this...

Comment: Updated answer to reach the element to explode